# Force TTY with Nagios check_by_ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, nagios

Is there a way to force tty allocation using the check_by_ssh plugin for Nagios.  Like the `-t` option for normal ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an option you can set with `-o` to force TTY allocation so I don't see an easy way without hacking the check_by_ssh source to add `-t` to the arguments array (& either adding an argument to check_by_ssh that controls it or rebuilding as check_by_ssh_with_tty).

The check_by_ssh code is pretty clean, so it wouldn't be painful to do - just `comm_append('-t')` as appropriate.  I can't vouch for how SSH will act if its not attached to a TTY on the client end though, one of those things I've never tried :)